# Can't use both pagestyle and tocloft package to add dots to table of contents and remove "chapter 1" before its name on headers

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext, color}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,tmargin=2cm,inner=1.5cm,outer=1.5cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[proportional,scaled=1.064]{erewhon}
\usepackage[erewhon,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\graphicspath{{./images}}
\geometry{left=3cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering} 
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}{0pt} 
{\normalfont\large\MakeUppercase}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=it}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=it}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\newpagestyle{mine}{
  \headrule
  \sethead{\ifthechapter{\chaptername\ \thechapter\quad}{}\hfill\chaptertitle}{} {}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}
     
  \pagestyle{mine}
  \begin{document}
```

I want two things to process correctly:

1. There should be dots in the tableofcontents between pagenumbers and names
2. There shouldn't be "chapter 1" text on headers of pages, only the name to the right.

dots work with tocloft package, but \tableofcontents is "Undefined control sequence". If I don't use this package, I can't put dots to the tableofcontents.

What is the correct way to make both things work?